# Universal prepared statement for update

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

A question: I deal with lots of update statements that at this moment I add to the ArrayList and then pass the array list to the function that loops over all update statements. They are not prepared.

How would you address this? I am thinking about 'universal' update function which receives lists of tables and parameters and then 'prepares' everything.

```
public void updateFromList(ArrayList<String> updateQueriesList) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@:1521:", "", "");

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        for (String s : updateQueriesList) {
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(s);
            pstmt.addBatch();
        }

        pstmt.executeBatch();

       con.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're asking is really possible. Not easily at least and without some work arounds that would make for bad unreadable code.

My suggestion would be to have a "major" update statement for each table that you are trying to update. One function per table. Then you would pass in objects that would be used to prepare the statement no matter what information they may contain. You would then loop the through the list of objects and call the "major" update statement on each one.

In this solution you don't add any statements to a list, you just have one statement within your major function that applies to all data that may ever go in that table.

Example:

```
public class ObjectToBeUpdated
{
  //data
  //getters and setters
}

public void updateObject(ObjectToBeUpdated object) {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@:1521:", "", "");

        String sql = UDPATE_STATEMENT with ? for parameters

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, object.getValue1()); //etc
        //get all values from object passed in and set them in order

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();

        connection.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    finally {
      connection.close();
    }
}
```

This is a very common way of doing it a lot of applications that allow for readable and very manageable code that only has to apply to one type of object/table at a time.